# android custom dialog with scrollview pushes buttons off the screen

Tags: android, layout

I have a custom dialog with a layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mylayout">
   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/title"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical">
       <TextView ... />
       <TextView .../>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
       android:id="@+id/scrollView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/title">
       <LinearLayout ...>
           <TextView ...
              android:text="lots of text........" />
           <TextView .../>
       </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView
  <RelativeLayout ...
     android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView">
     <Button ...>
     <Button ...>
  </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is that the scrollview is that when there is too much text in the scrollview, the buttons below are pushed down out of the dialog. I've been able to prevent it by anchoring the RelativeLayout that contains the buttons to the bottom using android:layout_alignParentBottom="true", but I that stretches the entire dialog to the bottom of the screen when there is less text in the scrollview and I don't want that.

How can I get a layout like this:

```
[SOME TEXT]
[Scrollable region]
[Buttons]
```

Comment: Try fixing the height of the main layout like 300dip

Comment: I don't want to fix the height of the main layout because it needs to be resizable on different screen sizes and orientations

Answer (score 9):

Try `LinearLayout` instead of the `RelativeLayout` Put the buttons in a separate layout and put a weight on the buttons layout.

```
LinearLayout - top level start, android:layout_weight="0"
LinearLayout with TextViews embeded, android:layout_weight="1"
LinearLayout with ScrollView embeded, android:layout_weight="1"
LinearLayout with Buttons embeded, android:layout_weight="1"
LinearLayout - top level finish, android:layout_weight="0"
```

Comment: Even using a linear layout container with a weight=1 attribute, the buttons are still pushed down and are cut off half way. So it's slightly better, but not a complete solution...

Comment: change the top layout to `LinearLayout` as well. Then have something like this: update I posted it in the answer...

Comment: hm...no luck, the dialog still stretches beyond the screen and pushes the buttons so they're half cut off. I have some margins on my buttons and text, would they effect the layout calculations?

Comment: Strangely, what made it work was setting the title layout weight to 0, the scroll view layout weight to 1 and the buttons layout weight to 0

Comment: That's true. The lower the number in the weight, the more preference it gets to be on the screen ;) Glad it works now!

Answer (score 3):

Even though the question is kind of old here is what helped in my case. Hope this may help others as it took me quite a while to down trace.

```
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(null);
```

Comment: The question asked about a custom dialog, not an alert dialog.