# Android: equal button size without ellipsizing or truncating button text

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a set of four buttons in a dialog layout that i make appear and disappear as needed depending on the data being displayed.  i want the buttons at the bottom to have the same size (the size of the largest button) and always stretch to fit the text on the button on a single line without truncating or ellipsizing.  code and screenshot included:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dip">
    <!-- this layout is the message count bar -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/count"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            style="@style/CustomDialog.TextColor"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- this layout is the title bar -->
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                style="@style/CustomDialog.TextColor"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- this is the body -->
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/body"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    style="@style/CustomDialog.TextColor"/>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- and this is where the buttons go -->
    <TableLayout
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="1">
        <TableRow>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Truncating Dialog Text]

Also, when the body text is too large, the buttons end up going away to make room for the text.  I need the exact opposite behavior (buttons are always shown in their entirity, and body of dialog is truncated).  Example:

[image: Truncating Button Height]

Comment: could you at least post the correct layout?

Comment: As far as I can tell you only need to switch the TableRow to a LinearLayout set to horizontal orientation. The root layout could be either RelativeLayout or LinearLayout with vertical orientation.

Comment: updated with full xml layout.

Comment: at most, how many buttons would be visible together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i adapted the answer from this question to my needs: [android custom dialog with scrollview pushes buttons off the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710947/android-custom-dialog-with-scrollview-pushes-buttons-off-the-screen)

the layout is as follows.  it does keep the buttons from disappearing into the bottom of the screen when the dialog content is too large, and the button text doesn't truncate anymore, but the buttons are no longer equally sized.  *if i could get the buttons to draw as wide as the widest button in the button panel, this would be perfect*.  <-- (please comment if you know how to achieve this):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip">
    <!-- this layout is the message count bar -->


    <!-- this layout is the title bar -->
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            >
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:id="@+id/count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    style="@style/CustomDialog.TextColor"/>
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    style="@style/CustomDialog.TextColor"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- this is the body -->
    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/body"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/CustomDialog.TextColor"/>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="none"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="none"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="none"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="none"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- and this is where the buttons go -->
    <!--<TableLayout-->
            <!--android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:stretchColumns="*">-->
        <!--<TableRow>-->
            <!--<Button-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/button1"-->
                    <!--android:gravity="center"-->
                    <!--android:visibility="gone"-->
                    <!--android:singleLine="true"-->
                    <!--android:layout_weight="1"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>-->
            <!--<Button-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/button2"-->
                    <!--android:gravity="center"-->
                    <!--android:visibility="gone"-->
                    <!--android:singleLine="true"-->
                    <!--android:layout_weight="1"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>-->
            <!--<Button-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/button3"-->
                    <!--android:gravity="center"-->
                    <!--android:visibility="gone"-->
                    <!--android:singleLine="true"-->
                    <!--android:layout_weight="1"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>-->
            <!--<Button-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/button4"-->
                    <!--android:gravity="center"-->
                    <!--android:visibility="gone"-->
                    <!--android:singleLine="true"-->
                    <!--android:layout_weight="1"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>-->
        <!--</TableRow>-->
    <!--</TableLayout>-->
</LinearLayout>
```

the secret is apparently in the weights of the three top level layout tags.  title is `layout_weight="0"`, body is `layout_weight="1"`, bottom button panel is `layout_weight="0"`.  no idea why this works...

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `TableLayout` with the following:

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

You can play programatically with `visibility` in `Visibility.VIEW` and `Visibility.GONE`.

In the above layout i have hidden the first `button` using `android:visibility="gone"` and  spread the three buttons across equally. So the uniform look with `buttons` is achieved.

However if you have only one `button` visible then you may have to set its `layout_width` to `wrap_content` else it would spread across your `dialog` `width`.

Using a `TableLayout` isn't necessary for your requirement.

Comment: I haven't forgotten about you.  I'll supply the bounty as soon as I confirm that this solves both problems stated in the question.  Thanks!

Comment: buttons still truncate at the bottom as they do in the second image.

Comment: i used the same layout with all four buttons divided equally,worked fine for me, did you remove the table layout

Comment: when the dialog body is too long, the buttons still don't get drawn at the bottom, as in image 2 in the question.  also the buttons still truncate the button text.  this doesn't solve either problem brought up in the question.  yes, i tried replacing the TableLayout with the code you provided.  nothing changed.